# Getting links out of a string and putting them in an arraylist

Tags: java

So, I wanna make a Java program which alerts me when there's a new thread on a subreddit.
I'm fairly new, so let's do this.

I managed to put the enitre html in one string, but now I want to index all the links in the string and put them in an arraylist.

Then I'll create a method which checks if the link is already in the arraylist, and if it's not, there's a new thread.

So let's say I've got the String; webpage. How would I get all the href="*" out of the string, and into a arraylist?

Comment: Do you have a delimiter that you use in your string to separate the links? If not, show the string sample so that we can help out.

Comment: Do you know reddit has an API? http://www.reddit.com/dev/api It it is much better idea to use it instead of trying to parse HTML.